# Python: no loop, how do i run a line of code every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I have a Raspberry Pi that runs a script like the following that counts pulses from a GAS meter. The `button.when_pressed = post_to_mqtt(1)` is activated when a electrical connection is made.  However, sometimes the script stops sending messages to the mqtt server even though "ps -aux" shows its still running.  A common method to get around this is to have a line of code that sends an alive MQTT message to the server.  From the server side, if you don't receive the message, an alarm is raised and manually dealt with. However, im not sure how to do this, there's no loop, just a pause.  How do send a MQTT message every 5 minutes using the code structure below

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def post_to_mqtt(pulse_count):
        print("this is working")
try:
    # initialise GPIO
    button = Button(pin_sensor)
    button.when_pressed = post_to_mqtt(1)
    while True : 
       #post_to_mqtt(0)
       print("this is real")
       time.sleep(1)
```

After some comments, ive updated the code to the below, its now not counting the pulse counts.  Any any ideas?

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def post_to_mqtt(pulse_count):
        print("this is working")
try:
    # initialise GPIO
    button = Button(pin_sensor)
    button.when_pressed = post_to_mqtt(1)
    while True :
       print("post to mqtt alive packet")
       time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Replace the `pause` with a loop that sends your MQTT message every five m inutes.

Comment: Whats the purpose of pause?

Comment: The `pause` statement does nothing, forever. It prevents your script form exiting so that the threads handling your `button.when_pressed` event continue to operate.

Comment: And if I do that, will that stop "button.when_pressed = post_to_mqtt(1)" from triggering if a pulse is detected while its executing the newly written loop code (?

Comment: I think your best bet is to try out what I suggested, and if it doesn't work, show us the updated code and explain what behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks,  the other question I have is if "button.when_pressed = post_to_mqtt(1)" is activated and say the loops is online 2, will the loop continue to line 3 or go back to line 2.